# How to get Rows that falls in between dates and get their child Rows in another table - Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I want to create a single query that will fetch all `Event`s that fall between dates.
I also want to get all their child `EventImage`s.

Can I get all of this into a single query?

**Event Model**

```
public function eventImages()
    
{
        
return $this->hasMany(EventImage::class, 'event_id');
    
}
```

**Event Images Model**

```
public function event()
    
{
        
return $this->belongsTo(Event::class);
    
}
```

**Sample Query for getting Events between dates**

```
$events = Event::whereBetween('date', [$start_date, $end_date])
            ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
            ->get();
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should already be able to access them. To make sure, their are included in [serialization](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-serialization), you can [eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) them via `with()`.

```
Event::with(['eventImages'])
            ->whereBetween('date', [$start_date, $end_date])
            ->orderBy('date', 'ASC')
            ->get();
```